# HP Photosmart 7450 Prints Noise On Windows 7 Pro 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, troubleshooting, printer, hp-photosmart

I have received a working (in its last location) HP Photosmart 7450 printer.  I connected it up to my Windows 7 Pro 64-bit workstation, and the driver was (apparently) installed.

The problem is that whenever I try to print from it -- test page, text from notepad, picture, whatever -- it spins through a half dozen sheets of paper, some of which have fractions of text on them, but most of which are either blank or have line noise printed on them.  Noise similar to what was printed out on ye olde laserjet printers when the postscript interpreter failed.

HP's web site only has a "use the included driver in Windows 7, be happy" instruction.

The driver has been removed and added several times.

The printer was previously attached to a XP Home computer and (allegedly) worked correctly without incident.

Does anyone have any ideas for troubleshooting before I drop this printer in the river?

**Update:**  Just for giggles I downloaded the XP driver and installed the printer software into a XP VM running on the Windows 7 system and then had VMware connect the printer to the VM.  When asking for a test page, I get two blank pages and then the test page although it looks like one of the ink reservoirs is empty/blocked.  When I do a "sample page" from the driver, I again get two blank pages and then a the sample page, again looking like it is missing one or more reservoirs colors.  So maybe I need to buy a new ink cart for this printer.

Comment: Does the printer's internal test page(s) print as expected?

Comment: Printer doesn't seem to have an internal menu function I can access.

Comment: I just came back from my neighbor's house with a similar problem for her Photosmart 7550 printer on Win 7 64-bit.  Got the "use the included driver in Windows 7, be happy" message from the web site but it also said to try loading the Deskjet 5550 driver and "it should work for most of the printers features".   It didnt.  I'll be paying attention to see if anyone else has ideas on this one too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: the printer is broken.  Threw it away and bought a new printer.